# Is there a variable "like" $PROGRAMFILES that is set to match bit width of target system?

Tags: 64-bit, nsis

I need to change an installer script to put the files into `C:\Program Files (x86)` for 32 bit and `C:\Program Files` for 64 bit.

I'd hoped `$PROGRAMFILES` was the right variable to use but from the docs, this always points to `C:\Program Files (x86)`.

```
"The program files directory (usually C:\Program Files but detected at runtime).
On Windows x64, $PROGRAMFILES and $PROGRAMFILES32 point to C:\Program Files (x86)
while $PROGRAMFILES64 points to C:\Program Files. Use $PROGRAMFILES64 when
installing x64 applications."
```

I'm familiar with how to test the system at install time with `${If} ${RunningX64}` but there are dozens of `$PROGRAMFILES` entries in the script so I'd like to avoid that approach if at all possible.

Is there a different variable that gets set automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no program files variable that matches the system. `$PROGRAMFILES` matches the bitness of the installer.

If you need to match the bitness of the system then you have to create your own variable and initialize it in `.onInit`. `$PROGRAMFILES64` probably degrades to `$PROGRAMFILES32` on 32-bit systems but I'm not sure if I would endorse using it like that.

This is usually not an issue because you should be using `$InstDir` when referencing the destination folder.